# ABPersonCopyImageData leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, addressbook, allocation

I have big problem with getting images from AddressBook, below I paste my code. This imageData never has been deallocated, on my Allocations Instruments it looks that it`s always in memory it never release.

```
@autoreleasepool {
            CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(record);
            if(imageData)
            {
                CFRetain(imageData);
                CFRelease(imageData);
                imageData = NULL;
                imageData = nil;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are over-retaining `imageData`

```
CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(record); // Returns a +1 owned object
if(imageData)
{
    CFRetain(imageData);     // This is now +2
    CFRelease(imageData);    // This is now +1
    imageData = NULL;        // You've lost the pointer that lets you release it
    imageData = nil;         // Does nothing.
}
```

Having this in an autoreleasepool does nothing as you don't have any autoreleased objects.

Have a look at the [Core Foundation Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html)

Comment: It nothings change, same situation.

CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(record); // Returns a +1 owned object
if(imageData)
{
CFRelease(imageData);
}

Comment: I was commenting your code to show you what you were doing wrong. You need to remove the CFRetain call

Answer (score 0):

You need to `CFRelease(imageData )` when you are done with it. Its a Core Foundation object - the autorrelease pool does you no good.

Comment: I use it only once in this moment "CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(record);", I don`t use it anymore. I want get cfdataref and release it immediately.

Comment: You don't make any sense. So you release it now, and the problem is gone? Then just say that - and either mark this as the correct answer, or answer your own question then select it with what you did. Ah, you changed the code since I answered - fine select @Abizern's answer.